# Bash completion makes bash start slowly

Tags: ubuntu, performance, bashrc, tab-completion

Starting a bash on my ubuntu system takes about 2 seconds.
If I remove loading /etc/bash_completition in .bashrc it starts without delay.
Of course I don't want to give up completition and I don't think loading that file is legit reason for a 2 seconds delay.

Any ideas how i can find out what the problem is or how i can speed things up.

Comment: is this /bin/bash ? - try /bin/dash might be a bit quicker.

Comment: This is why I deinstalled bash-completion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Update in 2013: Most of bash-completion was rewritten to autoload completions only when needed. The core script is much ligher now.*

---

The completion script can sometimes be *huge* in shell script standards. On one servers I have access to, it's almost 1700 lines (57 KB) and that's just the *core script*. In `/etc/bash_completion.d` there are ~200 additional scripts for various other commands (`openssl`, `mutt`, `mount`...) totalling 25537 lines or 1.2 MB. Each script, when sourced, checks if a command is actually available before defining completion handlers; ~330 times in this case, each of which involves checking `$PATH` for an executable file with a given name. (Although I would expect `/usr/bin` to be cached in memory...)

Admittedly, even *that* only takes half a second to load, not two full seconds. But it might be at least part of the problem. Run *`du -hs /etc/bash_completion*`* or *`wc -l /etc/bash_completion{,.d/*} | grep total`* if you want to check.

---

You can try manually sourcing the script, in "trace" mode:

```
set -x
. /etc/bash_completion
```

You'll see each line as it is executed. If there's a particular command that takes a long time, you should notice it.

(`set +x` disables the trace mode.)

Comment: Feature creep even in simplistic text mode? It's more likely than you think.

Comment: @Vi: After seeing zsh compile its startup scripts to bytecode...

Comment: Thank you. Thats was really easy. Sadly all commands were not noticable different. So it looks like its indeed the massive amount whats causing the problem.

Answer (score 12):

I found a bit hackish solution that seems to work fairly enough.

## Solution

At the bottom of `~/.bashrc` add:

```
trap 'source /etc/bash_completion ; trap USR1' USR1
{ sleep 0.1 ; builtin kill -USR1 $$ ; } & disown
```

## Explanation

`trap 'source /etc/bash_completion ; trap USR1' USR1`

Setup an handler to be run when the shell receives the signal `SIGUSR1`; the handler will load the completions and hence it will deactivate itself.

`{ sleep 0.1 ; builtin kill -USR1 $$ ; } & disown`

Asynchronously wait a bit then send the signal to the current shell. `disown` is needed to suppress `bash` process control feedback. `sleep` is needed to work asynchronously.

## Problems

For some reason the first command issued to this shell will not be recorded in the history.

Comment: This doesn't seem to give a startup boost - `time bash -lc true` reports ~0.12s with or without this, even though `time source /etc/bash_completion` reports *higher* numbers like 0.26s. Has this effectively been [fixed](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=467231)?

Comment: I don't know if `time bash -lc true` works properly here since `true` finishes before `~0.1s` so it doesn't source anything. Anyway `time source /etc/bash_completion` reports ~0.17s here and that's about the time I need to wait for the `PS1` appear.

Comment: Ingenious! In explanation, the trap commands misses a `USR1` at the end.

Comment: With SIGUSR, the signal handler is not invoked until after I press enter at the shell prompt.  There is a pause at that point while it runs. I switched to SIGQUIT and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 5):

You should use the lastest version (2.0) of bash_completion.
If you're using Debian, it's in wheezy, but it has no dependencies on any other wheezy package, so you can install it on a squeeze with no issue.

The lastest version loads completion dynamically on the fly, so it divided the prompt load time for me by at least 10x.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a placeholder while the completions are loading; it should be enough to trick your eyes. This obviously work only if the time needed by `source /etc/bash_completion` is less than the time needed by you to type and issue the first shell command, otherwise it will be delayed as well.

The idea is to echo a fake `PS1`, source the completions and finally erease the terminal.

Suppose that your `PS1` is `\u@\h:\w\$`, they you might write something like:

```
echo -ne "$USER@$HOSTNAME:${PWD/$HOME/\~}\$ "
source /etc/bash_completion
echo -ne '\e[2J\e[H'
```

Where:

- `2J` erases the terminal;
- `H` move the cursor to the upper right corner.

---

**Note:** You may want to check if the user is root and use `#` instead of `$` for consistency:

```
echo -ne "...$([ $UID = 0 ] && echo '#' || echo '$') "
```

---

**Note:** Removing `\e[2J` avoids the flickering but it will leave junk characters if the placeholder is longer than the actual prompt.